# Pull Request for only selective commits

Tags: git, github

I'd like to make a PR for some changes I'm ready to make to an [open-source project](https://github.com/Provenance-Emu/Provenance). I've forked the repository and made the [changes](https://github.com/Provenance-Emu/Provenance/wiki/Installing-Provenance#build-source) necessary to get the app to run. Those changes (we'll call them Commit #1) are specific to my build, so they should exist only on my fork and not be included in any pull request to the main repo. A second set of changes (Commit #2) is what needs to be included in a PR.

In order to successfully build and run the code, I must have Commit #1 as I'm developing Commit #2. For this reason, I've included Commit #1 in the feature branch I plan to make a PR from. Once I'm ready to submit Commit #2 for inclusion in the main repo, **how can I make a PR that includes only Commit #2 but not Commit #1?**

I performed the following steps in an attempt to do this:

- Fork the main repo
- Make changes and commit (Commit #1)
- Create and switch to a feature branch
- Make more changes and commit (Commit #2)
- Push to my fork

**Observed**: The feature branch in my fork contains both commits, thus I can't use it for a PR due to it including changes intended only for my fork (Commit #1).

**Desired**: I'd like the feature branch to only contain Commit #2 so I can use it for a PR.

What should I have done in order to still be able to build locally (i.e. have the necessary changes from Commit #1), but create a PR that includes only the changes from Commit #2?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new branch based on the upstream, and then `cherry-pick` the one commit you want to send upstream into that branch.

```
git checkout -b for-pull-request origin/master
git cherry-pick <Commit #2 SHA>
git push origin for-pull-request
```

And then make a pull request using the `for-pull-request` branch.

Comment: If I understand you right, I'm going to need 3 branches: `master` (which tracks origin/master + Commit 1), `feature-dev` (branched off of `master` so it also includes Commit 1 - this is where I do my development for this feature) and `feature` which tracks origin/master, doesn't include Commit 1, and gets pull requested. I need to manually cherry-pick (into `feature`) each change as I make them to `feature-dev` if I want them to show up in the pull request. Is there an easy way to tell git to "cherry pick all the commits newer than my current commit" so I don't need to manually specify them?

Comment: You can cherry pick a range of commits e.g. `git cherry-pick master..feature-dev` will cherry-pick all of the commits that are in `feature-dev` but not in `master`.

Comment: Another option is to do most of your work in `feature` and just keep commit 1 in `feature-dev`, and keep rebasing `feature-dev` on top of `feature` (which keeps moving commit1 on top of whatever changes you've made). This however would have the downside of making it harder to experiment, since you'd be doing the work first on the non-functional branch. Probably not what you want.